# What does "model.trainable = False" mean in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to freeze a pre-trained network in Keras. I found `base.trainable = False` in the documentation. But I didn't understand how it works.
With `len(model.trainable_weights)` I found out that I have 30 trainable weights. How can that be? The network shows total trainable params: 16,812,353.
After freezing I have 4 trainable weights.
Maybe I don't understand the difference between params and weights. Unfortunately I am a beginner in Deep Learning. Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 11):

A Keras `Model` is [trainable by default](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L154) - you have two means of freezing all the weights:

1. `model.trainable = False` *before* compiling the model
2. `for layer in model.layers: layer.trainable = False` - works before & after compiling

(1) must be done before compilation since Keras treats `model.trainable` as a boolean flag at compiling, and performs (2) under the hood. After doing either of the above, you should see:

```py
print(model.trainable_weights)
# []
```

---

Regarding the docs, likely outdated - see linked source code above, up-to-date.

Comment: If a `Model` contains nested `Model`s in its `layers`, then I assume that the code in option (2) would actually result in option (1) behavior for these nested models, right? In that case, it would be better to have a function `set_trainable` that recursively iterates through the `layers`, sets `trainable` for layers and calls itself again for nested models.

Comment: @KilianBatzner Indeed, a recursive approach is safer: `if isinstance(layer, Model): set_trainable(layer)`.